# Android in-app-billing not showing "This is a test order" and wants to charge the test user

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I added a test user to the console and after waiting 3 hours the app still wants to charge the user and its not showing "This is a test order".
What steps could I be missing?

I do get the correct item and price so I know that part is working and the servers updated.

Comment: is the version being tested in either the alpha or beta channel?

Comment: Is it a subscription?

Comment: Its in Alpha, published.   Its not a subscription, its a Managed Product.

Comment: How did you add this user?  to the alpha channel group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that everything was fine, but I was a little inpatient.

After 4 hours the user started to get "this is a test order...." message.

Answer (score 0):

I think your product not active now. For determine moment of activating product in Google Play you can change name (not id) of your product and wait for new name in your app. Later rename product for correct.

Comment: product is active because I see the product and it gives me the right description and price.